# If EMV can't be copied/cloned, how will companies like plastc do it?

Tags: emv

It is widely spread that EMV chips can't be copied or cloned onto another card like the information on a magnet strip.

How will companies like [plastc](https://www.plastc.com/) (a rewritable card) do it?

Any Ideas?

Comment: Who says this doesn't drive them out of business instead?

Comment: The problem with depending on non changing standards is when it changes.

Comment: if you believe their FAQ https://www.plastc.com/faqs they can clone EMV cards, however this seems ... unlikely

Comment: "Re-writeable EMV (support **not available** at launch)".